# Need a little bit of help finishing a generic MySQL select method

Tags: c#, mysql

**General info**
I'm busy writing my own MySQL database class inside C#. At the moment I'm trying to write a Select method that accepts a select query and returns a List with all the data. I'm still very new to C# so if my approach to this problem is wrong, please do not hesitate to tell me.

**The problem**
Right now my method expects 2 parameters. The query and the number of columns selected by the query. With that info I prepare my List and start filling it up. To do this I'm relying on the amount of columns with a foreach loop. However, I have no idea on how to get the correct column names
when adding to the List. Aside from that, I'm not sure if my approach is going to work. So I hope you guys would like to take a look at my method and help me out finishing it.

**The method**

```
public List<string>[] Select(string query, int items)
{
    //Create a list to store the result
    List<string>[] resultList = new List<string>[items];

    for(int i = 0; i < items; i++)
    {
        resultList[i] = new List<string>();
    }

    //Open connection
    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        //Create Command
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        //Create a data reader and Execute the command
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        //Read the data and store them in the list
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < items; j++)
            {
                resultList[j].Add(dataReader["columnName_here"] + "");
            }
        }

        //close Data Reader
        dataReader.Close();

        //close Connection
        this.CloseConnection();

        //return list to be displayed
        return resultList;
    }
    else
    {
        return resultList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`MySqlDataReader`](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDataReader.html) is derived from [`System.Data.Common.DbDataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader(v=vs.110).aspx), so you can use this code to get the columns:

```
for (int c = 0; c < dataReader.FieldCount; c++)
{
    string name = dataReader.GetName(c);
    Type type = dataReader.GetFieldType(c);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I found the solution myself at the same time you posted it, haha :) Great job!